# How to filter order by order number using $in operator in WIX Api

Tags: laravel, postman, velo

I am currently working on a project where I need to retrieve orders from the Wix API based on their order numbers using the $in operator. However, I am facing an issue with the filter, and I'm receiving the following error message:

```json
{
   "message": "Invalid long filter 'incrementId $in [10028.0]'",
   "details": {
       "applicationError": {
           "code": "SE-1105",
           "description": "Invalid long filter 'incrementId $in [10028.0]'"
       }
    }
}
```

Here is the JSON data I am sending through Postman:

```json
{
   "query": {
       "filter": "{\"number\":{\"$in\":[\"10028\"]}}",
       "sort": "[{\"dateCreated\":\"desc\"}]",
       "paging": {
           "limit": 10,
           "offset": 0
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the [documentation](https://dev.wix.com/docs/rest/api-reference/wix-stores/orders/filter-and-sort), number filtering does not support the `$in` operator.

`$hasSome` matches that the numbers matches one element of the search array. So use the following solution.

```
"filter": "{"number":{"$hasSome":["10028"]}}",
```